# Nimbus framework, using CocoaPods, with the Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK

Tags: ios7, xcode5, cocoapods, nimbus, jsonkit

Endless issues here:

1. `Nimbus` itself is bloated and less maintained every day
2. I feel, I am forced to upgrade `Nimbus` from `0.9.3` to `1.0.0` for various reasons
3. Upgrading `Nimbus` from `0.9.3` to `1.0.0` has lots of changes (e.g., `AFNetworking`)
4. Latest `podspec` depends on `JSONKit`, which won't build out–of–the–box, because of ARC/deprecation issues

Anyone could/did manage to build with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK for, at least, iOS 7 target?

Comment: same problem for me too. I'm a little lost as to how to get over the jsonkit problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to define my own specs for CocoaPods [here](https://gist.github.com/exalted/7655606).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.